# JS Drag&Drop on Firefox / Android not working

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, drag-and-drop, ecma

I am working on a drag & drop quiz where i can sort items into two areas.

Sadly it is not working in Firefox Mobile on Android. If i touch the items nothing happens. But i wonder why...

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>

<div class="step">

    <div class="handles">
    
        <div class="handle" id="handle4" data-target="omnivor" draggable="true">Meat</div>
        <div class="handle" id="handle1" data-target="vegan" draggable="true">Cocoa</div>
        <div class="handle" id="handle2" data-target="vegan" draggable="true">Banana</div>
        <div class="handle" id="handle3" data-target="omnivor" draggable="true">butter</div>
    
    </div>

    <div class="targets">
        <div id="target1" class="target">vegan</div>
        <div id="target2" class="target">omnivor</div>
    </div>

</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {

    // handles-container auf feste hoehe setzen, damit er fix bleibt
    let handlesContainer = document.querySelector(".handles");
    handlesContainer.style.height = handlesContainer.offsetHeight+"px";
    
    // Handles draggable machen...
    let handles = document.querySelectorAll(".handles .handle");
    
    handles.forEach(function(e) {
        
        e.addEventListener("dragstart", function(e) {
        
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', this.id);
            this.classList.add("drag-start");
        
        });
        
        e.addEventListener("dragend", function(e) {
        
            e.stopPropagation();
            this.classList.remove("drag-start");
        
        });
        
    });
    
    // Targets empfaenglich machen...
    
    let targets = document.querySelectorAll(".targets .target");
    
    targets.forEach(function(e) {
    
        e.addEventListener("dragenter", function(e) {
        
            e.preventDefault();
            this.classList.add("drag-enter");
        
        });
        
        e.addEventListener("dragleave", function() {
        
            this.classList.remove("drag-enter");
        
        });
        
        e.addEventListener("dragover", function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
        });
        
        e.addEventListener("drop", function(e) {
            
            e.stopPropagation();
            this.classList.remove("drag-enter");
            
            let elmnt = document.getElementById(e.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain"));
                
                if(elmnt.dataset.target == this.innerText) {
                    console.log("korrekte zuordnung");
                }
                else {
                    console.log("Zuordnung falsch");
                }
        
            elmnt.remove();
        });
    
    });
    
});
```

Here is my codepen:

https://codepen.io/kili123/pen/MWByGVE

I want to make the itams draggable and droppable on all modern browsers..

Comment: drag and drop works differently for touch devices

Comment: Sorry thats not helpful

Comment: How is that not helpful? It is not a solution it is a hint that you have to look into drag and drop for touch devices and add it to your code.

Answer (score 1):

It's not supported in FF Mobile

https://caniuse.com/?search=draganddrop

---